# O emulador só roda aplicações antigas

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Criei uma app a algum tempo e estou criando outro agora, porém quando inicio o `emulador`, o `app` que aparece é o antigo. Não consigo mexer no novo `app` no emulador.

O que pode estar acontecendo ?

Comment: Tem certeza que a nova versão está sendo gerada corretamente pela `IDE`?. Qual `IDE` está utilizando, `Visual Studio` ou `Xamarin Studio`? Já tentou remover a versão antiga do emulador?

Comment: Na verdade precisava de uma atualização, agora roda normalmente. Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro olhe no output da aplicação para ver se encontra alguma evidência ou mensagem. Geralmente, quando o deploy não é feito, alguma mensagem aparece descrevendo o problema.

Porém recomendo desinstalar o App do Emulador. Pode ser que você não encontre o app na lista de apps do seu Android (ou Emulador). Sendo assim, vá até as configurações, selecione a opção Applications, encontre-o e remova-o.

Exclua todas as pastas bin e obj do projeto e dê um rebuild.

Acredito que isso vá resolver!